# angular2 story for angular 1.x ng-include

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Looking at angular 2.0 directives https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiType=Directive i'm not seeing any support for the angular 1.x directive ng-include https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude for "Fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment."

My understanding is that this may have been done away with in lieu of the "multiple components" story outlined here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html.

If that is the case then i'm stuck on why my attempts to use that approach, e.g.

```
<my-template [objRef]="detailRecord">child component/class view goes here</my-template>
```

in this simple plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/dxTvNmM0hUUEqntffiLL?p=preview is not producing the result i'm looking for.

Comment: Here's the [end of the story](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2753), and it's not a happy ending.

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks for pointer to past issue covering what happened to this and DynamicComponentLoader alternative that I will also try out.  I would have expected the ng2 multiple components / master-detail component option outlined in tutorial link noted above to also be a viable solution . . . but i must have something messed up with that implementation in plunkr example referenced where I was trying to get that option working.